# Local storage with HTML5 | Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a game using HTML5 for awhile and it's getting to the point where downloading the assets on load is becoming quite a hassle. I've created patchers for games before, so doing so wouldn't be an issue but I'm not sure how to go about storing the data.

LocalStorage only allows around 5MB of storage, which isn't enough for anything larger than a basic 2D game's worth of assets.

Considering my game is almost 70MB now (It's not too large, but definitely not something you want to wait to load every-time you open it, especially as a developer) it's becoming a necessity to use some form of disk storage for reading/writing data. (Game models, Music, Client code)

Is this possible and if so how should I go about it? I'm expecting the full size of the game to end at around 220-270MB when we go into Closed Beta from Alpha and that's way too much to download every time apposed to checking file validation and updating what needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I would try [to cache some content on the browser](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching?hl=en) and use [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) if possible.

P.S: You may be interested on this project too: [LargeLocalStorage](https://github.com/tantaman/LargeLocalStorage)